# static analysis of open source projects

Tags: java, open-source, static-analysis

we started with static code analysis and I would like to see how we compare with other projects. Now I am aware I could go out and run tools for different OS projects, but I was curious if there is a repository for this data. such as 
cyclomatic complexity, code coverage, size of methods, size of classes, scope nesting, etc

thanks
almir

Comment: Coverity did scan different source projects with their tool a few years back: https://scan.coverity.com/ However I don't know whether they also checked for the code metrics you mentioned. On the other hand it isn't difficult to run Findbugs, PMD or the like on different projects yourself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Ohloh.net](http://www.ohloh.net) has a few of the metrics you mentioned
2. [FLOSS Metrics](http://flossmetrics.org) may have some
3. [FLOSSmole](http://flossmole.org) - includes [data from the now-defunct SourceKibitzer](http://flossdata.syr.edu/data/sk/2007/) though it's a little old (2007), as well as the [same metrics run on Debian packages in 2011](http://flossdata.syr.edu/data/deb/debMetrics/)
4. [Sourcerer](http://sourcerer.ics.uci.edu) may have some

Comment: sourcer does not work, at least I get 404 for the search page, others are quite old and there could be more data. but at least its start :). thanks

Answer (score 1):

For Java OS projects a free monitoring system with some metrics is available here: http://opensource.quality-gate.com/